# How to Install Reporting Services Report Viewer WebPart?

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I'm trying to use the Reporting Services Report Viewer WebPart with a project that I'm working on and I can't seem to get a clear indication on exactly where it comes from (or maybe I just don't understand?).  [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326422(SQL.90).aspx) indicates that it's "installed by the Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint Technologies".  However, I can't seem to figure out exactly where/what that is.

Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Yeah, I found it a pain to find as well.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think I just [found it](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1E53F882-0C16-4847-B331-132274AE8C84&displaylang=en)!